# How do I use a stopper-borer?

Tags: tools, technique

I need to bore a small hole in a rubber stopper (bung) like this:

[image: rubber stopper]

I have a set of tools called stopper-borers like these:

[image: stopper-borers]

But I can't figure out how to use them. Simply pressing on the borer doesn't get me very far as the rubber is hard enough to resist the sharp end of the tool, but soft enough to absorb the pressure I apply and simply deform momentarily.

The tools didn't come with any instructions and I can't find any on the web. Does anyone have any experience using stopper-borers on rubber stoppers?

Comment: I don't see how this relates to home improvement, but you twist them as you press into the stopper.

Comment: hehe "I need help with my bung hole".  Seriously though, is the plug your working with hollow?  if so try creating the hole from the other side.

Answer (score 8):

The idea is that you have to **slice**, not push. Also these do not work for silicone rubber stoppers, they do work for natural rubber and cork stoppers.

Well, I should say under human power. If you take the handle off the tube end of the borer and put it into a drill, like a bit, and use it that way, you will be able to drill through the silicone bungs.

**Important** Use lubrication, other wise you won't even get close to making a hole. It would be like trying to go down a slide made of velco while wearing a sweater.

Comment: glycerin makes decent lubricant, that will not corrode the rubber later on.

Answer (score 2):

There are rubber stopper borers. the cork ones have small serrations, and the rubber borers are just smooth and sharp. I cant tell from the picture, which you have, but I have had far better use using a drill press, an placing a rubber mat under the stopper. it will keep it from sliding around while you drill into it.